# Logical Equivalence for Quantified Statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have the following predicate:

P(x,y) = x is better than y

and was given the following quantified statement for the sentence "exactly one person is better than Sam":

$$\exists x [P(x, Sam) \land (\neg \exists y P(y, Sam)\land (y \neq x))]$$

I am wondering if this is logically equivalent to:

$$\exists x \exists y[(P(x,Sam) \land P(y,Sam)) \rightarrow (x = y)]$$

Intuitively I can't see why they are not, but am having a difficult time converting one to the other via logical laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. $\neg \exists y \phi \not \equiv \exists y \neg \phi$, so you can not apply the negation just to the conjunction and move the existential quantifier out. What is the negated is the existence of other better persons. Note also that the $\exists y$ is supposed to scope over the whole second conjunction; it's $P(y,Sam) \land (y \neq x)$ which belongs together, but in your second sentence you changed the bracketing structure so as to $P(x,Sam)$ to belong to the first part and applying the negation just to $y \neq x$.

The second sentence can be satisfied in a structure where noone is better than Sam. Because then for arbitrary choices of $x$ and $y$ the conjunction becomes false so the implication becomes true so the existential statement becomes true, which is not the intended meaning.
The first sentence entails the second, but not vice versa, so they are not equivalent.

A logically equivalent transformation via logical laws is

$\begin{align*}
& \exists x [P(x, Sam) \land \neg \exists y [P(y, Sam) \land (y \neq x))]\\
\equiv\ & \exists x [P(x, Sam) \land \forall y \neg [P(y, Sam)\land (y \neq x)]]\\
\equiv\ & \exists x [P(x, Sam) \land \forall y [P(y, Sam) \to (y = x)]]\\
\end{align*}$

Comment: How can the second statement mean that no one is better than Sam? I comprehend it as given an arbitrary x, y in the class, if x and y are better than Sam, then x and y are the same people? and P(x,Sam) and P(x,Sam) is logically equivalent to P(x,Sam).

Comment: As I said: If noone is better than Sam, than for whatever values of $x$ and $y$, $P(x,sam)$ is false and $P(y,sam)$ is false so $P(x,sam) \land P(y,sam)$ is false so $(P(x,sam) \land P(y,sam)) \to (y = x)$ is true so $\exists x \exists y [(P(x,sam) \land P(y,sam)) \to (y = x)]$ is true. Could be that $y = x$ or that $y \neq x$, it doesn't matter, the implication comes out true anyway.

Comment: Right - I see! Thank you!

Comment: My one follow up question: What about the case when P(x,Sam) is True, P(y, Sam) is False, and (y=x) is True. That is a true statement but contradictory, no?

Comment: That would be contradictory, so it can not possibly become true.

Comment: But it's a true statement? Can you elaborate on this situation or point me in the direction of where I can read more into it? Is it just that we can simply derive a contradiction from the statement and thus it would hold false in that case?

Comment: The combination of truth values you give just can't arise given what the statements mean. If they did take these truth values, then yes, the statement would be true, but that won't ever happen.